# Window transparency changing affecting active windows

Tags: autohotkey

I have a code for hiding a window with AutoHotKey:

```
NumpadEnter::
Trans:=255
Loop
{   
    WinSet, Transparent, %Trans%, A
    Sleep, 20
    Trans-=1
    if(Trans <= 0)
        Break
}
return
```

Works like a charm, but you can see that execution time of this function is about 4-5 seconds. I can't switch between other windows in these 4-5 seconds, because other windows will be affected with WinSet function.

I need to save window handle to variable before the loop. And use it on the line with WinSet function.

How can I do that?

Comment: Post the code that you tried. It should work.

Comment: See my working example code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the winexist() function with the A option as the wintittle parameter, that will give you the ID of the active window so that you can use that.

Something like this

```
NumpadEnter::
hWnd := WinExist("A")
Trans:=255
Loop
{   
    WinSet, Transparent, %Trans%, Ahk_id %hWnd%
    Sleep, 20
    Trans-=1
    if(Trans <= 0)
        Break
}
return
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You can hide window using Windows built in transition effects dll. You can do many different transitions and they are all smooth as they are processed by the OS. I will post code tomorrow.

Comment: GoogleThis  WinFade()

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

The full documentation:  http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80577-how-to-animate-a-gui-window/

**Edit 2:**

You mentioned it didn't work for you. Here is a **working example** on Windows 8 machine using Ahk_L (aka. Autohotkey_L or Autohotkey_Lexiko):

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On ;//Allow hidden windows to be detectable
SetWinDelay, -1 ;//Make Window update very fast (smooth animation)

FADE       := 524288
SHOW       := 131072
HIDE       := 65536

FADE_SHOW  := FADE+SHOW
FADE_HIDE  := FADE+HIDE

SetFormat, Integer, Hex
FADE_SHOW+=0 ;//Converts to 0xa0000
FADE_HIDE+=0 ;//Converts to 0x90000
SetFormat, Integer, d

Gui, Font, w500 s35 Center, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, , Hello! This Window will hide in 5 Seconds.
Gui, Show, NA Hide, Test Window ; //Create the Window hidden
Gui, +LastFound
GUI_ID := WinExist() ;//Get Window ID

Duration := 3000 ;//Speed of Window showing/hiding

DllCall("AnimateWindow","UInt",GUI_ID,"Int",Duration,"UInt", FADE_SHOW) ;//Fade in Window
Sleep, 5000 ;//Pause for 5 seconds
DllCall("AnimateWindow","UInt",GUI_ID,"Int",Duration,"UInt", FADE_HIDE) ;//Fade out Window
Return
```